# KnockoutJS foreach sometimes not displaying results

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I don't have a code sample to reproduce (situation is too complex), however the scenario I have is this:

I have a KnockoutJS (version 3.1.0) "foreach" binding against a computed() property. 
The computed property returns data based on the value of another observable property, plus a few filters based on observables (i.e. return all bookmarks in the selected category, plus filter by any search terms).

My problem is "sometimes" (and randomly) no results would be displayed for a category that I know has results. I would select another category and [usually] results are displayed, then when I re-select the category that did not show, results suddenly appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment to another question ([knockout js data binding not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319021/knockout-js-data-binding-not-updated?rq=1#comment28616516_19319021)) allowed me to discover the answer.

I watched the Javascript console in the browser and discovered I was getting an error:
"Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference"

By fixing this (by first checking the value - incidentally, a KO observable - being converted to lower actually has a value) and stopping that error, the view consistently displays data now.

The Console is your friend!